# Add dynamic type to a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uisearchbar, dynamic-type-feature

My question is pretty much stated in the title. I'm trying to add dynamic type (as defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/)) to a `UISearchBar` with no luck. I know this is possible as the system apps seem to be able to handle it just fine as shown here:
[image]

However, my app doesn't seem to be handling that so well as shown here:

[image]

Knowing that `UITextField` is contained within `UISearchBar` I naturally tried this solution without success:
`UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true`

I've also tried searching online/checking documentation but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Is there something I'm missing to get dynamic type working in a `UISearchBar`.

Update:
@matt suggested I do a manual check and update the font that way. However, that is yielding another issue as the search bar itself is too small to fit the text as shown here:
[image]

@matt suggested to update the height as well using the `scaledValue(for:)` method, however this doesn't seem to work. Here's the code I'm using:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        let textFieldFrame = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).frame
        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).frame = CGRect(x: textFieldFrame.minX, y: textFieldFrame.minY, width: textFieldFrame.width, height: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: textFieldFrame.height))
}
```

The font seems to now be scaling with this updated code, yet the search bar's height isn't growing:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    searchBar.textField?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    if let textFieldFrame = searchBar.textField?.frame {
        searchBar.textField?.frame = CGRect(x: textFieldFrame.minX, y: textFieldFrame.minY, width: textFieldFrame.width, height: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: textFieldFrame.height))
    }
}
```

Also, here's how I found the textField (just in case other users who get stuck would like to know):

```
extension UISearchBar {
    var textField: UITextField? {
        var _textField: UITextField? = nil
        subviews.forEach {
            $0.subviews.forEach {
                if let textField = $0 as? UITextField {
                    _textField = textField
                }
            }
        }
        return _textField
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic type"? It's not clear what your issue is. And the tag `dynamictype` doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question (read the tag description).

Comment: Oops my bad.. I mean the "dynamic type: defined here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/. I will update the question.

Comment: @matt Hmm.. I have watched that video in the past and I'm looking at it again right now. I believe it only let's you get like an ideal spacing/ideal font based on the text style. Do you think you could link me to the specific API and I could take  look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed these milestones to reach your goal:

- Automatically Adjusts Font with the Dynamic Type feature *(STEP 1)*.
- Adapt the searchbar constraints *(STEP 2)* **AND** its textfield constraints *(STEP 3)* when a new [preferred content size category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXht1.png) occurs.

  ```
  class SearchBarDynamicTypeVC: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!

  let fontHead = UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 20.0)
  let fontHeadMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .title1)
  var initialFrameHeight: CGFloat = 0.0


  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).font = fontHeadMetrics.scaledFont(for: fontHead!)

      mySearchBar.textField?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true //STEP 1
  }


  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)

      initialFrameHeight = mySearchBar.intrinsicContentSize.height

      if let textField = mySearchBar.textField {
          adaptConstraints(textField) //Initialization according to the first preferred content size category
      }
  }


  override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
      super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

      if let textField = mySearchBar.textField,
          let _ = previousTraitCollection {

          adaptConstraints(textField) // STEP 2 & 3
      }
  }


  private func adaptConstraints(_ textField: UITextField) {

  //  Adapt the SEARCHBAR constraints
      mySearchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(mySearchBar.constraints)

      let heightSB = mySearchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fontHeadMetrics.scaledValue(for: initialFrameHeight))
      let widthSB = mySearchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20)
      let centerVSB = mySearchBar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
      let centerHSB = mySearchBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)

      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerVSB,
                                   centerHSB,
                                   widthSB,
                                   heightSB])

  //  Adapt the SEARCHBAR TEXTFIELD constraints
      textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(textField.constraints)

      let centerXTF = textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.superview!.centerXAnchor)
      let centerYTF = textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.superview!.centerYAnchor)
      let widthTF = textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.superview!.widthAnchor, constant: -20.0)
      let heightTF = textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.superview!.heightAnchor, constant: -20.0)

      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerXTF,
                                   centerYTF,
                                   widthTF,
                                   heightTF])
  }
  }
  ```

I used the code snippet provided in your post to get the searchbar textfield:

```
extension UISearchBar {

    var textField: UITextField? {

        var _textField: UITextField? = nil

        subviews.forEach {
            $0.subviews.forEach {
                if let textField = $0 as? UITextField {
                    _textField = textField
                }
            }
        }
        return _textField
    }
}
```

However, you can also get it using the key `searchField` as follows:

```
let textField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
```

The snapshots hereunder show the final result:

[image]

You can now **add dynamic type to a UISearchBar** by adapting the code snippet above and customizing the visual personal choices *(text style, font, margins...)*.

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you tell why we need the constant -20 for textfield height and width?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry: I suggest to change the values and notice the changes in the appearance.